# NoReverseMatch - How to add url parameter to render?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Is there any method to provide `url` argument in case of `render` or any other solution? Somehow I need to provide `user_url`.

```
# view
def create_gallery(request, user_url):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        extended_form = GalleryExtendedForm(request.POST, prefix="extended_form")
        basic_form = GalleryForm(request.POST, prefix="basic_form")
        print(request.POST)
        if extended_form.is_valid() and basic_form.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        extended_form = GalleryExtendedForm(prefix="extended_form")
        basic_form = GalleryForm(prefix="basic_form")

        return render(request, 'galleries/gallery_create_n_update.html', 
                     {'extended_form': extended_form,
                      'basic_form': basic_form})

# core.urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<user_url>[\w.-]+)/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profiles_user')),
]

# profiles.urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^gallery/', include('galleries.urls')),
    # ... lots of others urls
]

# galleries.urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add/$', views.create_gallery, name='gallery-add'),
]
```

Error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'gallery-add' with arguments '('',)'
and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<user_url>[\\w.-]+)/gallery/add/$']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `user_url` into the `context` parameter of `render()`, so that it can be used in the template.

Then, inside the template, you can add `user_url` as a parameter to the [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url), like this:

```
{% url 'gallery-add' user_url=user_url %}
```